# Jq: how to extract from map of maps?

Tags: jq

I have

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "clients": {
        "c1": {
            "updated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "instances": {
                "i1": {
                    "updated": "2023-03-19T17:45:03.703984279+01:00",
                    "chargePower": 349.9999940395355
                }
            }
        },
        "c2": {
            "updated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "instances": {
                "i2": {
                    "updated": "2023-02-10T18:34:56.352428175+01:00",
                    "chargePower": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and would like a map of instance id (i1...) and the map it has associated like this:

```json
{
    "i1": {
        "updated": "2023-03-19T17:45:03.703984279+01:00",
        "chargePower": 349.9999940395355
    },
    "i2": {
        "updated": "2023-02-10T18:34:56.352428175+01:00",
        "chargePower": 0
    }
}
```

I get as far  as

```
.clients | to_entries | .[].value.instances
```

which gives

```json
{
  "i1": {
    "updated": "2023-03-19T17:45:03.703984279+01:00",
    "chargePower": 349.9999940395355
  }
}
{
  "i2": {
    "updated": "2023-02-10T18:34:56.352428175+01:00",
    "chargePower": 0
  }
}
```

but fail to convert that back to a map. Here's a jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/FMnrrUIV27U

Comment: You could use with_entries, then you just have to update .value

Comment: What is your expected output? Please [edit] your question to include your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question right (it is lacking the expected output), but if you are looking for an object with the instances' keys as keys, then you could use [`map`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#map(x),map_values(x)) on the parent objects and [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#add) on the resulting array of nested objects:

```
.clients | map(.instances) | add
```

Or a [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Reduce)-based approach:

```
reduce .clients[].instances as $i ({}; . + $i)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "i1": {
    "updated": "2023-03-19T17:45:03.703984279+01:00",
    "chargePower": 349.9999940395355
  },
  "i2": {
    "updated": "2023-02-10T18:34:56.352428175+01:00",
    "chargePower": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.clients | with_entries(.value = (.value.instances | to_entries[0].value))
```

Will update the `value` of the `key` with the `first` value of `instances`

```
{
  "c1": {
    "updated": "2023-03-19T17:45:03.703984279+01:00",
    "chargePower": 349.9999940395355
  },
  "c2": {
    "updated": "2023-02-10T18:34:56.352428175+01:00",
    "chargePower": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: This creates a client/details, but not an instance/details map. Still interesting to better understand the usage of `.value`.